# Tell Jekyll (on github pages) to convert README.md to README.html, not index.html

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I am using Jekyll to build a project webpage, on Github Pages, using the “Dinky” theme, straight out of the box.

The `README.md` gets automatically converted to `index.html`, which is very helpful for quickly getting started.

However, I would like to have a separately-written main page `index.md`, and instead convert `README.md` to `README.html` (as it does with most `*.md` files).  When I add my `index.md`, Jekyll converts it to `index.html` as hoped, but now gives no conversion at all of `README.md` — presumably it has `index.html` as the target for both `README.md` and `index.md`, and the latter wins.

**How do I tell Jekyll to go back to using `README.html` as its conversion target for `README.md`?**

**Preferably, I would like a solution that doesn’t require adding config data in `README.md` itself**, so that I can continue to keep `README.md` in sync with the human-readable version in the `master` branch.

Note for reproducing it: all this occurs both when built online through Github Pages, and with a local `jekyll build`.  The only custom jekyll settings I am using are `gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins` in the site’s `Gemfile`, and `theme: jekyll-theme-dinky` in the site’s `_config.yml`.

It seems to be specific to the Github Pages themes, but not to the Dinky theme: other themes beside Dinky exhibit the same behaviour, but a bare Jekyll site does not seem to.

---

Edit: thanks to @wasthishelpful for a very helpful comment and partial answer.  Adding a YAML frontmatter block to `README.md` setting `permalink: README.html` does what I was looking for.  Unfortunately I’m still not finding a way to achieve the same effect just by modifying `_config.yml`: e.g. adding a frontmatter default there

```
defaults:
  - 
    scope:
      path: "README.md"
    values:
      permalink: "README.html"
```

doesn’t seem to have any effect.  (I’ve tried both with and without the quote marks around the filenames, and both before and after the line `theme: jekyll-theme-dinky`.)

Comment: Readme.md displays a quick overview at the root of the repo when visiting Github, but none of them generates an index.html in a Jekyll website

Comment: @marcanuy: I know Jekyll wouldn’t normally convert `README.md` to `index.html`, but when using Github Pages with a theme, I assure you it does.  I will edit my answer to clarify what I’ve tried, but briefly, this happens both in a local build and when served through Github Pages, and I’ve got no local custom settings except those used for the Github Pages theme.

Comment: I can't reproduce it, never seen that README.md gets converted to `index.html`.

Comment: @marcanuy: very peculiar — thankyou for trying!  The project itself is at https://github.com/UniMath/TypeTheory/tree/gh-pages, so you can see the full setup.  Currently it has both `index.md` and `README.md`, so as described in the question, `index.html` gets generated from the former and nothing from the latter; but if I delete `index.md`, then `index.html` gets generated from `README.md`.  (The github pages themes use `bundler`, so it may need something like `gem install bundler && bundler install` if you haven’t got that installed already.)

Comment: Did you try to use a [permalink](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) in `README.md`, or used [front matter defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults) for it in your `_config.yml`?

Comment: @wasthishelpful: thankyou very much for the pointer, that sounds just like what I was looking for.  Adding a permalink in `README.md` itself works fine, but adding it as a frontmatter default in `_config.yml` doesn’t work (unless I’m doing something wrong) — more details in question edit shortly.  If you make this an answer, I’d accept it, especially if you can give a way that works just in `_config.yml`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [permalink](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) in `README.md`:

```
---
permalink: README.html
---

TypeTheory: the mathematical study of type theories, in univalent foundations
==========

Code  on C-systems, D-systems, ...
```

You may also use [front matter defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults) in your `_config.yml`:

```
defaults:
  - 
    scope:
      path: "README.md"
    values:
      permalink: "README.html"
```

But you will still need a front matter in `README.md` to make it parsed by jekyll (even if it is an empty one):

```
---
---

TypeTheory: the mathematical study of type theories, in univalent foundations
==========

Code  on C-systems, D-systems, ...
```

Answer (score 5):

I learned that if you add *any* frontmatter to the readme, it stops turning README.md into index.html. I discovered this accidentally by adding this frontmatter to my README.md

```
---
title: Design Your Bot
---
```